# Create instance for a class interface in a single line?

Tags: oop, interface, abap, new-operator

Maybe it's a pretty basic question but I didn't manage to find out if it's possible or not.

Since 7.40, we have the **NEW** operator to create instances. It allows to create an object and call a method in a single line:

```
DATA(result) = NEW zclass( )->method( ).
```

But if my **zclass** implements a **zinterface**, I would like to do the following in a single line:

```
DATA: zif_instance TYPE REF TO zinterface.
zif_instance = NEW zclass( ).
DATA(result) = zif_instance->method( ).
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be three answers.

Either you use the [interface component selector](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/index.htm?file=abeninterface_comp_selector_glosry.htm) **`~`**:

```
DATA(result) = NEW zclass( )->zif_instance~method( ).
```

Or your class defines an alias to the interface method, say `method_alias`, via the [ALIASES](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/index.htm?file=abapaliases.htm) statement, i.e. `ALIASES method_alias FOR zif_instance~method` (NB: the alias could also be the same name as the original method name i.e. `method`):

```
DATA(result) = NEW zclass( )->method_alias( ).
```

Or you have the [CAST](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/index.htm?file=abensql_cast.htm) operator.

```
DATA(result) = CAST zif_instance( NEW zclass( ) )->method( ).
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I realise my question was not properly written, because what I wanted is to be able to actually compress either the first 2 or the last 2 lines, for when I have an interface variable that can be reused better than the specific class instance. Then the only valid solution to use CAST, but the current question and your answer is more informative so I leave it untouched.